How can I create a round hole in stiffener in Altium?
I am building a flat flex cable assembly. I have two regions Layer1 which has stiffener, and layer 2/3 with no stiffener. I don't see an option on the toolbar or in the menu to create a circle. I would like to create a round hole in the stiffener, how could I do this in Altium (using ver 24.6.1)?

But maybe doing this through the board planning mode is not the right way to go. Is there another layer that I create the hole on?

By layer manager do you mean board planning mode?

No, I don't have to do this in board planning mode, I just need a way to put a hole in the region.

I don't remember how i made the shape of the stiffener the last time i made a flat flex - I'll see if I can find it. But I think I if I were to do it again I would just dedicate a mechanical layer to it, draw the outline on that layer, and add the cutout in the stiffener with an annotation. 1/x

I don't think there is good support for assymetric buildups with only one copper layer in Altium yet (though changes are on the way), or else you could probably define the board as a rigid flex and define the section with stiffener as a rigid sub buildup. Then I guess the board cutout region tool would do it. But then I guess you'll get a cutout in the flex part of that section as well. Maybe not what you want?

Along those lines, perhaps the cutout could be its own board sub-region and you set the stackup there to be flex only?

I already have regions on the board that are flex only, the problem is drawing the polygon or converting a pre-existing one. I guess I could just draw the region by hand. Board cutouts show up in the board planner but only for a hole on all layers. I guess I could do this the old fasioned way and just define a mechanical layer with the cutouts.

I don't know offhand (I haven't used flex, board planner, etc.) but if it's like any other Region object, you might cheat by pinching a concavity: https://i.sstatic.net/wCeLhTY8.png

I was thinking you'd have to do something like that... I was envisioning making two different areas. Right now since I have to get this design done, I think I'll just create a mechanical layer for the holes and special instructions in the PCB fab document.
